# Comparing two dates in different tables SQL with criteria

Tags: sql, date-comparison

Click image to see the table structure and problm  https://i.stack.imgur.com/odWKL.png

[image]

```
SELECT B.ENTITYID, 
       B.BALANCEDATE,
       B.BALANCE, 
       MIN(DATEDIFF(DAY,B.BALANCEDATE,C.STATUSDATE)) RECENT
FROM   BALANCES B JOIN STATUS C ON B.ENTITYID = C.ENTITYID
GROUP  BY B.ENTITYID, B.BALANCEDATE,B.BALANCE
HAVING B.ENTITYID =1
```

I have tried the following but can't go further than that as more nested selects have problems with accessing similar attributes:

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `RDBMS` stands for *Relational Database Management System*. `RDBMS is the basis for SQL`, and for all modern database systems like MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also in SQLServer2005+ you can use option with [APPLY()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) operator.

The APPLY operator allows you to join two table expressions. Right table expression is processed every time for each row from the left table expression.The final result-set contains all the selected columns from the left table expression followed by all the columns of right table expression. OUTER APLLY for those rows for which there are no corresponding matches in right table expression, it contains NULL values in columns of right table expression.

```
SELECT e.EntityName, b.BalanceDate AS Date, b.Balance, o.Status
FROM Entity e JOIN Balances b ON e.EntityID = b.EntityID
              OUTER APPLY (
                           SELECT TOP 1 s.Status AS Status                           
                           FROM Status s
                           WHERE b.EntityID = s.EntityID 
                             AND s.StatusDate < b.BalanceDate
                           ORDER BY s.StatusDate DESC
                           ) o
WHERE e.EntityName = 'ABCD'
```

For improving performance(force INDEX SEEK operation) use this indexes with INCLUDE clause.The INCLUDE clause adds the data at the lowest/leaf level, rather than in the index tree. This makes the index smaller because it's not part of the tree

```
CREATE INDEX x ON Status(StatusDate) INCLUDE(EntityID, Status)
CREATE INDEX x ON Entity(EntityName) INCLUDE(EntityID)
CREATE INDEX x ON Balances(EntityID, BalanceDate, Balance)
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/aa3db/1)

[image]

Comment: First of all, Thank You all so much for the tremendous help. I marked Alexander's answer as the solution to problem since it is for SQL Server 2005+ ... Even though The example for SQL 2012 and MySQL are equally good, the sheer compatibility of Alexander's answer proved crucial for marking it as the solution. Thank you all

Comment: @talktome always keep in mind that when problems like this, **you should always specify the Database Server that you are using**. we are not psychic that can predict your server that you are using. `SQL` means *Structured Query Language*. It doesn't mentioned any server on the acronym.

Comment: @J W  ... My Bad, I missed the part to mention about the SQL Server. You are right about mentioning the Database being used. But anyhow, I hope it proves to be a blessing in disguise for people using SQL Server 2012 and MySQL .. Full Credit to you, your detailed answer and stupendous explanation.

Answer (score 4):

See [@ljh's Answer if you are working on SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15716497/491243). The solution below works on MySQL. It's a little bit messy since MySQL doesn't support `CTE` and `Window Function`.

## MySQL

```
SET @entity_name = 'ABCD';

SELECT  b.*, d.Status
FROM    Entity a
        INNER JOIN Balances b
            ON a.EntityID = b.EntityID
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  a.EntityID, 
                    a.StatusDate StartDate, 
                    b.StatusDate + Interval -1 DAY EndDate,
                    a.Status
            FROM
                    (
                        SELECT  b.*, @r1 := @r1 + 1 AS Row_number
                        FROM    `Entity` a
                                INNER JOIN Status b
                                    ON a.EntityID = b.EntityID
                                CROSS JOIN (SELECT @r1 := 0) rowCount
                        WHERE   a.EntityName = @entity_name
                        ORDER   BY b.Status ASC
                    ) a
                    LEFT JOIN
                    (
                        SELECT  b.*, @r2 := @r2 + 1 AS Row_number
                        FROM    `Entity` a
                                INNER JOIN Status b
                                    ON a.EntityID = b.EntityID
                                CROSS JOIN (SELECT @r2 := 1) rowCount
                        WHERE   a.EntityName = @entity_name
                        ORDER   BY b.Status ASC
                    ) b ON  a.Row_number = b.Row_number
        ) d 
        ON b.BalanceDate BETWEEN d.StartDate AND d.EndDate
WHERE   a.EntityName = @entity_name
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b1c32/2)

---

## The Brief Break Down

Since, MySQL do not support *Windowing Function* such as `ROW_NUMBER()`, the query below uses `User Variable` to provide row number similar to `ROW_NUMBER()` for every record which will then be used to join on the other subquery.

```
SELECT  b.*, @r1 := @r1 + 1 AS Row_number
FROM    `Entity` a
        INNER JOIN Status b
            ON a.EntityID = b.EntityID
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT @r1 := 0) rowCount
WHERE   a.EntityName = @entity_name
ORDER   BY b.Status ASC
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b1c32/3)

OUTPUT

```
╔══════════╦═════════════════════════════════╦════════╦════════════╗
║ ENTITYID ║           STATUSDATE            ║ STATUS ║ ROW_NUMBER ║
╠══════════╬═════════════════════════════════╬════════╬════════════╣
║        1 ║ May, 29 2010 00:00:00+0000      ║ A      ║          1 ║
║        1 ║ April, 16 2010 00:00:00+0000    ║ B      ║          2 ║
║        1 ║ April, 02 2010 00:00:00+0000    ║ C      ║          3 ║
║        1 ║ February, 26 2010 00:00:00+0000 ║ D      ║          4 ║
╚══════════╩═════════════════════════════════╩════════╩════════════╝
```

The main purpose of the provision of row number for the records is it will be used to join on another subquery so we can get the `StartDate` and `EndDate` for every `Status`. This is easy on `SQL Server 2012` because it has a Windowing Function called [LAG()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx)

```
╔══════════╦═════════════════════════════════╦══════════════════════════════╦════════╗
║ ENTITYID ║            STARTDATE            ║           ENDDATE            ║ STATUS ║
╠══════════╬═════════════════════════════════╬══════════════════════════════╬════════╣
║        1 ║ May, 29 2010 00:00:00+0000      ║ (null)                       ║ A      ║
║        1 ║ April, 16 2010 00:00:00+0000    ║ May, 28 2010 00:00:00+0000   ║ B      ║
║        1 ║ April, 02 2010 00:00:00+0000    ║ April, 15 2010 00:00:00+0000 ║ C      ║
║        1 ║ February, 26 2010 00:00:00+0000 ║ April, 01 2010 00:00:00+0000 ║ D      ║
╚══════════╩═════════════════════════════════╩══════════════════════════════╩════════╝
```

Once the Status Range has been organized. It is now the basis as the *LookUp* status for every `Balances`.

The final Result

```
╔══════════╦═════════════════════════════════╦═════════╦════════╗
║ ENTITYID ║           BALANCEDATE           ║ BALANCE ║ STATUS ║
╠══════════╬═════════════════════════════════╬═════════╬════════╣
║        1 ║ May, 01 2010 00:00:00+0000      ║     100 ║ B      ║
║        1 ║ April, 01 2010 00:00:00+0000    ║      50 ║ D      ║
║        1 ║ March, 01 2010 00:00:00+0000    ║      75 ║ D      ║
║        1 ║ February, 01 2010 00:00:00+0000 ║      85 ║ (null) ║
╚══════════╩═════════════════════════════════╩═════════╩════════╝
```

---

## SQL Server 2012

The query above demonstrated in `MySQL` can be easily converted in `TSQL` by using `Common Table Expression` and a `Window Function` which uses [**LAG() (*introduce in SQL Server 2012 only*)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx)

```
WITH lookupTable
AS
(
    SELECT  EntityID, 
            StatusDate StartDate, 
            DATEADD(DAY, -1, LAG(StatusDate) OVER(PARTITION BY EntityID ORDER BY Status)) EndDate,
            Status
    FROM    Status
)
SELECT  b.*, d.Status
FROM    Entity a
        INNER JOIN Balances b
            ON a.EntityID = b.EntityID
        LEFT JOIN lookupTable d
            ON b.BalanceDate BETWEEN d.StartDate AND d.EndDate AND
               d.EntityID = a.EntityID
WHERE   a.EntityName = 'ABCD'
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4a386/14)

OUTPUT

```
╔══════════╦═════════════════════════════════╦═════════╦════════╗
║ ENTITYID ║           BALANCEDATE           ║ BALANCE ║ STATUS ║
╠══════════╬═════════════════════════════════╬═════════╬════════╣
║        1 ║ May, 01 2010 00:00:00+0000      ║     100 ║ B      ║
║        1 ║ April, 01 2010 00:00:00+0000    ║      50 ║ D      ║
║        1 ║ March, 01 2010 00:00:00+0000    ║      75 ║ D      ║
║        1 ║ February, 01 2010 00:00:00+0000 ║      85 ║ (null) ║
╚══════════╩═════════════════════════════════╩═════════╩════════╝
```

Comment: hello..can you give explanation of your query.

Answer (score 2):

Using SQL Server 2012 as RDBMS as example. This is the 1st query you need. 
This answer utilized SQL CTE(Common Table Expression), which may not apply to other RDBMS system. 
**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1cc98/1)**
Explanantion of query:
1. First join [Balances] and [Status] table, use BalanceDate > StatusDate to filter out result, return all columns from both table, this is because all is needed later on. 
2. Join output from Step .1 with [Entity] table, use EntityName to filter out result, still leave all columns from 3 tables, certainly duplicate EntityID is not needed. 
3. Use CTE to save the join
4. Use CTE to save the rank applied on the join output
5. Use Rank number to filter out result and order by BalanceDate

```
;with CTE_AfterJoin
as 
(
    select E.EntityID, E.EnityName, C.BalanceDate, C.Balance, C.StatusDate, C.status
    from Entity E
    left join (
            select B.EntityID, B.BalanceDate, B.Balance,S.StatusDate, S.[Status]
            from Balances B 
            left join  [Status] S
            on B.EntityID = S.EntityID and B.BalanceDate > S.StatusDate
            ) C
    on E.EntityID = C.EntityID
    where E.EnityName = 'ABCD'
),
CTE_afterRank
as 
(
    select EnityName, BalanceDate, Balance, 
           rank() over (partition by BalanceDate order by StatusDate desc) as Rn, Status 
    from CTE_AfterJoin
)
select EnityName, BalanceDate, Balance, Status
from CTE_afterRank
where Rn = 1
order by BalanceDate desc
```